# Bluemix IoT "The topic is not valid"

Tags: lua, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

Using Bluemix. Using NodeMCU MQTT Lua. Get the following message about topic is not valid. How to debug?

---

Closed connection from 108.67.152.187. [The topic is not valid.] [6] times in the last [5] minutes

Token auth succeeded: ClientID='myClientID'

---

NodeMCU Lua code:

t1=123 -- arbitrary value

topic = "iotsensor.fake"

m:publish(topic ,'{"d": {"data":'..t1..'}}', 0, 0,

function(conn)
 -- Print confirmation of data published
 print("Sent message #"..count.." data:"..t1)
 end)

Answer (score 0):

For IoT Foundation:
Publishing events topic iot-2/evt/event_id/fmt/format_string

Subscribing to commands  topic iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/messaging/applications.html) for more details.